# Array don't change after splice and update its property

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a global array that can be accessed from multiple pages:

```
this.$root.$data.globalError.testArray
```

It contains:

```
export class GlobalError {
    testArray: Array<IDictionaryError> = [];
    ...
}

export interface IDictionaryError {
    index: number;
    errorList: ErrorType | null;
    numberError: number;
}

export interface ErrorType {
    [fieldName: string]: Array<ErrorItem> | string | null;
}
```

It is initialized in index.ts file like the following:

```
new Vue(
{ 
   data: {
     globalError: null,
   ...
}
```

In a function in page A, I splice this array and update property of its.

```
this.$root.$data.globalError.testArray.splice(indexSelected, 1);

this.$root.$data.globalError.testArray.forEach(item => {
  if (item.index > indexSelected) {
      item.index -= 1;
  }
});
```

This is the code in page B:

```
get countNumberError(): number {
 let total: number = 0;
 this.$root.$data.globalError.testArray.forEach(item => {
   total += item.numberError;
 });
 return total;
}
```

The things is if update the index like the foreach part above, when access this array in page B, this array keep all original elements (INCLUDE the deleted one).
If I don't update its property, the array will be updated in page B (NOT INCLUDE the deleted one).

I don't understand why? Please help me clarify it? And how can I update its property and keep this array updated in page B?

Thanks.

Comment: *If I don't update its property, the array will be updated in page B.* What do you mean, if you don't run the `forEach` bit the deletion works? And if you do run the `forEach` bit it is as if the deletion never happened?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If I don't execute "item.index -= 1;", the deletion works also.

Comment: Can you show the content of the `testArray`?

Comment: @acdcjunior: I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

You should use the third param of `forEach` array to edit this array

```
this.globalError.testArray.forEach((item, i, myArray) => {
  if (item.index > indexSelected) {
      myArray[i].index -= 1;
  }
});
```

Or you can use `.map`

```
this.globalError.testArray = this.globalError.testArray.map(item => {
      if (item.index > indexSelected) {
          item.index -= 1;
      }
      return item;
    });
```

Comment: @Tan Duong: thanks, but your solution doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason. The updating index `item.index -= 1;` triggered a function that unexpectedly reverse the array from the begining state.

Thanks for your help and sorry for this inconvenience.